# Video Can't play in ipad

Tags: php, ipad, video, web

i'm currently develop my website with wordpress and embedding a video in it, when I play the video it's ok in PC, but it isn't played in iPad. How to fix it?

the video extension is .*flv. Is it caused by the video extensions?

thx

Answer (score 0):

Most Modern Mobile OS's don't support flash (flv is flash video).

You are better off trans-coding the image to a more supported format and using the [html5 native video element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video).

[Most](http://caniuse.com/#feat=video) browsers support it but, for those living in the past, you can still use a [polyfill](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#video) that will fall back to flash.